# Axis_type="mercator" in bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I'm trying to run the chart given as example for Tile Provider Maps on the Bokeh geo-mapping site.

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/geo.html.

```
    from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.tile_providers import CARTODBPOSITRON

output_file("tile.html")

# range bounds supplied in web mercator coordinates
p = figure(x_range=(-2000000, 6000000), y_range=(-1000000, 7000000),
           x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator")
p.add_tile(CARTODBPOSITRON)

show(p)
```

But instead of the expected chart I'm getting:
ValueError: expected an element of either Auto or Enum('linear', 'log', 'datetime'), got 'mercator'

If I delete the x_axis_type paremeters (x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator") I'm getting the chart, though as expected, without latitude and longitute labels. Is there a problem in the script or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Your version of Bokeh is too old, you will have to update to [at least version 0.12.15](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7642) to use this feature